# Caveats with gzip --rsyncable - no speedup

Tags: rsync, gzip

I am using (trying) gzip to compress an SQL file in an rsyncable way in order to transfer the backup with minimal delay.

However it appears that this is not working, since the speedup is always 1.00.

The archive is created by dumping the database to a `.sql` file and then issuing `gzip -f3 --rsyncable file.sql`.

Next the remote machine does an rsync against the last backup with the following flags:

`rsync -avhhiP --inplace`

Why might my speedup be 1.00? Should I not be recreating the archive each time and instead updating it perhaps? I have seen no mention of this method from online guidance about the usage of the --rsyncable flag.

I am using:

```
# gzip -V
gzip 1.5
```

Comment: If `--rsyncable` is not listed in the `gzip --help`, the command doesn't support that option. I also have gzip 1.5 (Gentoo) and it doesn't have that option. The presence of `--rsyncable` option depends on whether the distribution has applied the patch that adds the option. Which distribution do you have?

Comment: If you want the option, you will need to apply the patch and build gzip.

Comment: Ah, I thought this should have been rectified since version 1.4. I checked both the `--help` output and the manpage, one mentions it but not the other although I'm not sure which specifically. This is on `Debian wheezy`.

Comment: OK, just checked and `--rsyncable` IS in the help output, but it's not in the manpage.

Comment: Have you tried without --inplace ? I don't know how rsync could not retransfer the whole file (or at least everything starting from the first modified block) if you ask it to update in place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is already somewhat old, but maybe my answer still helps one or the other:

Debian Wheezy has the aforementioned bug in gzip which renders the `--rsyncable`-flag non-functional.

See [the corresponding Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=708423).

You can use [`pigz`](https://packages.debian.org/de/wheezy/pigz) as a replacement, which is a parallelizing `gzip`-replacement which uses multiple CPUs, can compress slightly more efficiently if you manually specify larger block sizes and officially provides an `--rsyncable` implementation which is supposed to be better than the one provided by the `gzip` patch.

Additionally, `rsync`s `--inplace` parameter reduces the efficiency of the delta-transmission algorithm - to quote the manpage:

> The efficiency of rsync's delta-transfer algorithm may be reduced if some data in the  destination  file  is overwritten  before  it  can  be  copied  to  a  position later in the file.  This does not apply if you use `--backup`, since rsync is smart enough to use the backup file as the basis file for the transfer.

Comment: Note: that Debian bug was apparently fixed when gzip 1.6-3 was uploaded, Dec 2013.  This means it should work correctly in Jessie and later.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, Wheezy is affected. The patch works in all other versions of Debian that include it. Still `pigz` claims to provide a somewhat more effective `--rsyncable` flag.

Comment: I use `pigz` and rsync show no improvement :(

Answer (score 3):

I spent a long time trying to work out why `--rsyncable` wasn't working for me on Ubuntu 12.04 and gzip 1.4 before stumbling upon this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gzip/+bug/1021975

It appears there's a regression in the 1.4 ubuntu package which means that the rsyncable patch wasn't properly included in the release, despite it being listed in the `gzip --help`. I'm not sure whether it affects other distros or versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: damn on ubuntu 18.04 it stll not work

Comment: After a plethora of tests, I found out that due to algorimth, if you change thing in the file at the top of the list, rsync wont recognize the change, but add new file, it's very likely will speed up, see the example in the link https://github.com/facebook/zstd/pull/1416